# Sorting Object of ArrayList with combination of different Attributes

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, comparator, comparable

My class is like this:

```
class Employee{
  int age;
  String name;
  int empId;
  .
  .
  . 
 }
```

In the main method i have created the object of Employee class and save it in ArrayList say objEmpList.
Now,my requirement is to sort objEmpList like the SQL Statemnt as,
  Select * From Employee Order by age,name,empId;
Measn,i want the result sorted by the order of age,name & empId.

For eg:
  my data is like:
    10 Nirdesh 1
    10 Ambesh  222
     9 Ramesh  9
    12 Amar    3

So my result should be,

```
 9    Ramesh  9
 10   Ambesh  222
 10   Ramesh  1 
 12   Amar    3
```

How can i achieve this requirement?

Comment: Apart from the above comment - Have you done any research? Any google search?

Comment: I tried with adding the result of all atrributes with each hashcode() and subtracting with others with comparable Interface.But this is not working.

Comment: Ya i tired with google but cant find the soluation.

Comment: You should work with Comparable interface and attributes and implement your own algorith

Comment: @Nirdesh, check my answer below. You should be able to go with that!

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a new class EmployeeComparator that implements Comparator. Configure the order of fields by specifying a vararg list of field names `public EmployeeComparator(String... fields)`.

Here is an example:

```
public class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

private final List<String> fieldSortOrder;

public CarComparator(String... fieldSortOrder) {
    this.fieldSortOrder = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(fieldSortOrder));
}

@Override
public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
    try {
        return cmp(a, b, fieldSortOrder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

private int cmp(Car a, Car b, final List<String> fields) throws Exception {
    if (fields.isEmpty())
        return 0;

    PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fields.get(0), Car.class);
    String ma = (String) pd.getReadMethod().invoke(a);
    String mb = (String) pd.getReadMethod().invoke(b);
    if (ma.compareTo(mb) == 0) {
        return cmp(a, b, fields.subList(1, fields.size()));
    } else {
        return ma.compareTo(mb);
    }
}

}
```

Then have the list sorted like this:

```
Collection.sort(cars, new CarComparator("brand", "mileage"));
```

You will need accessors (i.e. getters and setters) for each field in your value object, and the example above will have a bit of trouble with non-string fields. But I guess I should leave some of the fun to you! :)

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for properly applying the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Answer (score 2):

**-** You can use `java.util.Compartor<T>` interface if you want to **sort on the basis of more than one attribute of the object.**

**-** You will have to use `Collections.sort(List<?> l, Comparator c)`.

**Eg:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Car {

    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private double cost;

    public Car(String name, String brand, double cost) {

        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return getName();
    }

}

public class Hog {

    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public void setIt() {

        cars.add(new Car("Padmini", "Fiat", 100008.00));
        cars.add(new Car("XYlo", "Mahindra", 100000.00));
        cars.add(new Car("Swift", "Maruti", 200000.00));
    }

    public void sortIt() {

        Collections.sort(cars, new NameComparator());
        System.out.println(cars);
        Collections.sort(cars, new BrandComparator());
        System.out.println(cars);
        Collections.sort(cars, new CostComparator());
        System.out.println(cars);
    }

    class NameComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

        public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {

            return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
        }
    }

    class BrandComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

        public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {

            return c1.getBrand().compareTo(c2.getBrand());
        }
    }

    class CostComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

        public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {

            return new Double(c1.getCost()).compareTo(new Double(c2.getCost()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hog h = new Hog();

        h.setIt();
        h.sortIt();
    }

}
```

Comment: This might end up with quite a few Comparators if there are many fields. Also, if you want to order by brand and then by cost, then you're in trouble, right?

Comment: @Markus, Well never felt the heat of this till now.... and i have been in a project which handles sorting of an object in 8 different ways.... Well the style of programming is quite argumental, i prefer it this way, as till now i have sailed quite flawlessly using this... It would be an honor and quite a learning experience if you can provide me with a better solution, i will be very grateful to you...

Answer (score 0):

make Employee implement Comparable, then call Collections.sort(list);

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    // rest of class omitted

    public int compareTo(Employee e) {
       // Here's how you order by age, name, empId
       if (age != e.age) return age - e.age;
       if (!name.equal(e.name) return name.compareTo(e.name);
       return empId - e.empId;
    }
}
```

Then

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: But inside compareTo() method,how do i sort based on these 3 attributes.

Comment: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: I am confusing on how should i implement the code for sorting.Can u write a code for implementing as above mentioned order

Comment: @Nirdesh: Try searching internet yourself. Its always good not to expect spoon feeding. Please take this in a Positive manner

Comment: @Nirdesh: Check my answer about using reflection. It's a hint on where to start your search.

Comment: @Nirdesh I have edited the answer to show how to code the ordering you asked for